# My background color goes further than the border in my table row, how do i fix it?

Tags: html, css

It happens in the bottom corners where my background color for my row doesn't respect the border radius set by the table, so the background flows out of the table and i can't fix it.
I tried playing with a border for the last row but it didn't let me modify the border radius, so i couldn't do anything.

The HTML is just a normal table.

[image: this is how it looks]

```
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Monday</th>
          <th>Tuesday</th>
          <th>Wednesday</th>
          <th>Thursday</th>
          <th>Friday</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>13:00</td>
          <td>Pizza</td>
          <td>Pasta</td>
          <td>Chocolate</td>
          <td>Banana</td>
          <td>Soup</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13:00</td>
          <td>Pizza</td>
          <td>Pasta</td>
          <td>Chocolate</td>
          <td>Banana</td>
          <td>Soup</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>18:00</td>
          <td>Chocolate</td>
          <td>Pasta</td>
          <td>Pizza</td>
          <td>Banana</td>
          <td>Soup</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid transparent 2px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(166, 89, 89);
  color: rgb(248, 215, 215);
}
table thead tr th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
table tbody tr td {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
table tbody tr:last-child {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.405);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply a `border-radius` the childs will still 'overflow' past the radius, it's only noticeable when a child has a background color.
you may resolve it by applying a `overflow:hidden` rule on the element that has the radius.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid transparent 2px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(166, 89, 89);
  color: rgb(248, 215, 215);
    /*you need to hide overflows for the border-radius items*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

table thead tr th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}

table tbody tr td {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

table tbody tr:last-child {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.405);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        head
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```